# VBA Macro Loop Until Blank Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a sheet with large data where I need to cut specific columns and paste in 1 column and have made a macro but need to loop it until it finds a blank cell.
This is my code

```
'
' Column Macro
'


'
    Range("E2:I2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Columns("E:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("E2:I2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Here I have fixed columns A-D whose values will be dragged down and values of every 5 columns after D i.e E-I need to be cut paste at the last blank cell of column E. So the columns after I will be shifted to E-I again which will be continually pasted at last cell of column E. In the code I had recorded macro for 2 instances of data paste. Now I need the macro as such that it will run till there are no data left to paste after column D.

Comment: Questions are expected to demonstrate reasonable effort to solve the problem. Your question lacks this.

Comment: Can you just please let me know what I need to add to make my question more clear, I can do that. I did a basic macro by recording and some edits based on my research.

Comment: Have you done a search for this? This question has been answered here many times here and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

Comment: I did do some research but needed help on my case specifically because I'm not into VBA coding. If anyone can help me out with this and can explain it, then I will be able to figure out the whole point citing my own example